# Android emulator ignores port argument

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

When I execute this command on port 5555 the emulator ignores the port argument and uses the default port (5554).

```
emulator -avd droid --port 5555 -no-boot-anim -no-audio
```

Does someone know why the port argument get ignored?

I get no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why it was not working.

The port number has to be even.

```
5554 -> even
5555 -> not even
5556 -> even
.
.
and so on
```

That's strange but this is how the android emulator works.